# Efficiency difference between Laravel+AngularJS && MEAN Stack?

Tags: web, laravel-5, lamp, mean-stack

Which of the below mentioned systems would be easier, efficient (as an end product), powerful, reliable, maintainable, also why/whyNot would it be?:

1_ Laravel + AngularJS

2_ MEAN Stack

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things for you to read:

http://thesimplesynthesis.com/post/node-js-vs-laravel

> Node.js and Laravel are brilliant frameworks. They both hold enormous
>   promise for the future and have some of the best features available of
>   any framework. But, they have their biases. If you have an application
>   with low computation and high availability requirements and are going
>   to use a BASE or non-relational database, Node.js is favorable. If you
>   have an application that is very complex and you need the highest
>   level of consistency and organization, and if you are working with
>   ACID / relational data, then Laravel is favorable.